# Why does rsnapshot not exclude directories I specify?

Tags: rsync, rsnapshot

I am setting up backups with rsnapshot but I'm having trouble with the excludes. I have read a lot about it and I know that there are important differences in rsync regarding the use of slashes. But I don't get why this doesn't work. My (simplified) folder structure inside `/path/to/files/my_files/` is something like this:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
-- subfolder1
-- subfolder2
folder4
```

I want to exclude `folder1` here. The rsync command in `/etc/rsnapshot.conf` is something like:

```
backup  remote_user@remote_server:/path/to/files/my_files/    my_files/
```

While my exclude file (also defined in `/etc/rsnapshot.conf`) looks like this:

```
- /folder1
```

I also tried `- folder1`, `- /folder1/`, and `- folder1/`. But none of them works the way I want. For example, using `- folder1` excludes the folder I want, but also every other folder whose path includes the string `folder1`. On the other hand, the others don't exclude the folder I want to exclude.

This really drives me crazy, I have read so many examples and it feels like I tried every possible combination - but to no avail. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is there something special about excludes in rsnapshot that makes it different from a simple rsync call? Because there I have no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsnapshot` invokes rsync with the `--relative` option. One of the things that this changes is the way include/exclude rules work.

Try this:

```
- /path/to/files/my_files/folder1
```

Comment: That actually seems to be the solution! Confusing.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to exclude a specific folder is to add an `exclude "path-pattern"` to `/etc/rsnapshot.conf` file:

```bash
# The include and exclude parameters, if enabled, simply get passed directly
# to rsync. If you have multiple include/exclude patterns, put each one on a
# separate line. Please look up the --include and --exclude options in the
# rsync man page for more details on how to specify file name patterns.
#
exclude         ".cache/"
exclude         "/path/to/your/folder"
```